# How to map a local port to a remote port without SSH access?

Tags: networking, macos, proxy

## What I want to solve

I have a configuration file that I do not want to change, because it is shared between many people and is managed by someone else. It has entries similar to this:

```
serviceAlpha: localhost:8081
serviceBravo: localhost:8082
serviceCharlie: localhost:8083
...
```

I would like to have the local ports each mapped to a remote host and port, without needing to login (tunnel) via SSH.

For instance:

```
localhost:8081 -> serviceAlpha:8080
localhost:8082 -> serviceBravo:8080
localhost:8083 -> serviceCharlie:8080
...
```

## What I have tried

I read that `/etc/hosts` is unable to solve this problem.

---

I have tried using `pf` (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248064/321244)):

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 8081 -> serviceAlpha port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

When I run `pfctl -s nat`, I get:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port = 8081 -> ww.xx.yy.zz port 8080
```

When I run `curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/`, I get `Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Operation timed out`. The same occurs when I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

When I run `curl -X GET http://ww.xx.yy.zz:8080/`, I get the expected response.

---

I have also tried various `socat` commands, including:

```
socat tcp-listen:8081 tcp:ww.xx.yy.zz:8080
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/health
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081: Operation timed out

socat tcp:127.0.0.1:8081 tcp:ww.xx.yy.zz:8080
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/health
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081: Operation timed out
> socat: 2019/02/14 16:27:02 socat[31221] E connect(5, LEN=16 AF=2 127.0.0.1:8081, 16): Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is using `Apache` and `mod_proxy`. You can check a full tutorial on how to setup `mod_proxy` [here](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/) (although it is for Linux, the steps for setting up should be similar). Especially check the section **Configure Apache For Proxy**.

So I think you can setup virtual host for each service and setup apache to listen to 8081, 8082, 8083.

Each virtual host configuration would look something like this:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://ww.xx.yy.zz:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://ww.xx.yy.zz:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is iptables. The commands are listed below:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp --dport 8081 -j REDIRECT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

I do not believe you are allowed to put a host name into the destination location, but you can try. These changes are not persistent; you need to drop them into a script that is run on startup for persistence.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your answer. I do not think I can use iptables because my machine is running macOS. From what I understand, the similar utility on macOS is `pf`, but I have not figured out the correct command/configuration.

Comment: Oh, that explains what rdr is. Looks like rdr piped to pfctl is the right command for OS X, and your example above seems to be using it correctly. Did you turn on the OS X firewall? `sudo pfctl -E` More examples of rdr usage:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/

Comment: Yes, the firewall is enabled. I checked System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall (On) and ran `sudo pfctl -e` which output `pfctl: pf already enabled`. That is one of the links I have been reading for some of my attempts. None are working yet.